# extracting bold letters from all rows of a column of given dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

this is the input : [image]

```
df2['status1']= ''

for i in df2.notes_1:

    doc = i

    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

    bold_words = soup.find_all('strong')

    string = bold_words[2].text + bold_words[3].text

    df2['status1'] = df2['status1'].append(string)
print(df2)
```

i have tried this. but unable to get the desired output. 
i have a dataframe that has a column named "notes_1" in which each rows has str that bold letters words between  . i need to append all bold letters words(the last 2 or 3 bold words)to each rows of a new column name " status1" in the same dataframe df2.

Comment: Why are you using `append` on `df['status1']`? What is the datatype of `status1`? And more importantly, while you added a screenshot of the example to show the input values, it is not sufficient, as the mot important part of the data is truncated and replaced with a `...`.

Answer (score 1):

[`pd.Series.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) is used to concatenate `pd.Series`es; not to concatenate a string to a `pd.Series` or a string to another string.

I would do [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on `df2["notes_1"]` with a function which does the extracting bold words part:

```py
def extract_bold_words(doc):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
    bold_words = soup.find_all('strong')
    string = bold_words[2].text + bold_words[3].text
    return string

df2['status1'] = df2['notes_1'].apply(extract_bold_words)
```

If you prefer a for loop, you can iterate through `df2['notes_1']`, [append](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) the results to a list, and finally make it a `pd.Series`:

```py
status1 = []

for doc in df2['notes_1']:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
    bold_words = soup.find_all('strong')
    string = bold_words[2].text + bold_words[3].text
    status1.append(string)

df2['status1'] = pd.Series(status1)
```

Comment: there is an error, list index out of range

Comment: IndexError     ----> 8 df2['status1'] df2['notes_1'].apply(extract_bold_words)
----> 5     string = bold_words[2].text + bold_words[3].text
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @AamerAshfaque Then you have to check what `bold_words` would be in such cases. I didn't change that part from your codes so it's another problem which can't be seen from your original question.

Comment: bold_words are bold words that are inside the string of each row, for example , the status has now changed from CV Submitted</strong> and CV Review </strong>to Interview1</strong>and Rejected</strong>. the words CV Review ,Submitted , interview1 and rejected are in bold.

Comment: @AamerAshfaque But it seems like the counts of bold words can be less than four or even three, right? That's how you got `IndexError` when doing `bold_words[2]` and `bold_words[3]`. You need to consider how to handle such cases. It's off the scope of this question.